# Removing rows based on a certain cell value in Excel Mac

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to remove hundreds of rows from my Excel file, where each of these rows have a cell containing the word 'V1'. I managed to find some VBA code online relating to my issue.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
'Updateby20140314
Dim rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range
Dim DeleteRng As Range
Dim DeleteStr As String
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
DeleteStr = Application.InputBox("Delete Text", xTitleId, Type:=2)
For Each rng In InputRng
    If rng.Value = DeleteStr Then
        If DeleteRng Is Nothing Then
            Set DeleteRng = rng
        Else
            Set DeleteRng = Application.Union(DeleteRng, rng)
        End If
    End If
Next
DeleteRng.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, every time I run the code where I select my cell range and input 'V1' as the value to remove the rows, I get the error message ‘Run-time error ‘13’: Type mismatch’. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Just to clarify - "V1" is being provided for the `DeleteStr` inputbox, right? And the type mismatch is occurring on which line? `If rng.Value = DeleteStr Then`? If so, verify that your `InputRng` doesn't contain any worksheet errors (e.g. `#N/A`, or `#VALUE!`). If there *are* worksheet errors, you need to use `IsError` to verify you're not looking at an error value *before* you attempt to compare that value with `DeleteStr`.

Comment: Also note, `= DeleteStr` will only pick up cells where the value *is* `DeleteStr`, not *contains*. Use the `InStr` function instead (if return value is `> 0` then you have a match), or use the `Like` operator instead of `=`.

Comment: Yes that's perfect. Thank you.